# how to write code for different code for different platform in react app

Tags: android, cordova, web

I am developing a web application, which I want to make it native. code for camera capture for the web, and native are different, how can I write code which executes for the particular platform?

Comment: Try to add more description.

Comment: @HarshPatel the question is too broad, more description won't help.